# Selecting postcode areas in MySQL by taking all characters that come before the first numeric character

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm trying to run a query to select the distribution of a certain set of postcode areas in an addresses table. A postcode area is the section at the start of a UK postcode consisting of either 1 or 2 letters, which comes directly before the first numeric character.

In the WHERE clause, I have specified the postcode areas of interest (EC, WC, E, and W) by indicating the composition of the first 2 characters, however I also need to be able to group by postcode area, which is where I'm having difficulty. In the SELECT clause I'm trying to specify postcode areas by taking all the characters of a postcode that come before the first numeric character. You can see my attempt below, but the REGEXP '[0-9]' part doesn't work. Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved concisely? Thanks in anticipation!

```
SELECT LEFT(postcode, LOCATE(REGEXP '[0-9]', postcode) - 1) AS postcode_area, COUNT(*)
FROM addresses
WHERE LEFT(postcode, 2) REGEXP 'EC|WC|(E|W)[0-9]'
GROUP BY postcode_area
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem shortly after posting, and just realised I didn't post my answer, so here it is:

```
SELECT LEFT(postal_code, IF(postal_code RLIKE '^[A-z][A-z]', 2, 1)) AS postcode_area, COUNT(*)
FROM addresses
GROUP BY postcode_area
HAVING postcode_area IN ('EC', 'WC', 'E', 'W')
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't offer a "regular expression" substring operation.  Perhaps the easiest way is to be explicit:

```
select left(postcode,
            (case when substr(postcode, 2, 1) between '0' and '9' then 1
                  when substr(postcode, 3, 1) between '0' and '9' then 2
             end)
            ) as postcode_area
```

You can put this into a query like this:

```
select left(postcode,
            (case when substr(postcode, 2, 1) between '0' and '9' then 1
                  when substr(postcode, 3, 1) between '0' and '9' then 2
             end)
            ) as postcode_area, count(*)
from addresses
group by postcode_area
having postcode_area in ('EC', 'WC', 'E', 'W');
```

I am not familiar with your use of `locate` and `regexp`.